# Invoking Lua functions the Python way i.e. named arguments

Tags: c++, lua

I've about 50+ C++ functions that accept a fix number of arguments say 25+. Think of these arguments as members inside a data structure.

Each function implements a business logic where it may or may not need to read/check values of all the 25 arguments. So, some functions may be interested in only 2 values while others with multiple checks could look up 15+.

Some sample functions as under:

**C++**

```
void DrawSegment(int length);
void DrawCircle(int radius);
void DrawRectangle(int width, int height);
void DrawCube(int side);
```

My task is to provide an easy to use interface method in Lua to call these functions. Something like,

```
DrawShape("CIRCLE", 20)
DrawShape("RECTANGLE", 10, 20)
```

**Lua-C++ binding code:**

```
enum TYPE{SEGMENT, CIRCLE, RECTANGLE, CUBE};

lua_Integer MapStringToEnum(const char*);

int lua_DrawShape(lua_State*L)
{
        lua_Integer type = MapStringToEnum(lua_tointeger(L, -1));
        switch (type)
        {
        case SEGMENT:
                DrawSegment(lua_tointeger(L, -2)); // length
                break;
        case CIRCLE:
                DrawCircle(lua_tointeger(L, -2));  // radius
                break;
        case RECTANGLE:
                DrawCircle(lua_tointeger(L, -2), lua_tointeger(L, -3)); // width, height
                break;
                ...
                //and so on for other types
        default:
                ASSERT(0);
        };
}

initShapeLibrary(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_pushcfunction(L, lua_DrawShape);
    lua_setglobal(L, "DrawShape");
}
```

The challenge that I'm facing is since each function does not require all arguments, how do I make it easier for the user to specify these fields ? One way is to document the arguments and their ordering and expect the user to follow it. But this would just result in an unreadable code forcing the user to specify null values or empty strings for arguments he does not intend to pass.

```
-- 1st argument is radius, 2nd unused.
DrawShape("CIRCLE", 20, -1)
```

This is not code friendly. What I would really like is a Python like facility like that allows the code to be readable.

```
DrawShape("CIRCLE", Radius=20)
```

Is there anyway to achieve this via Lua? If not, I am planning to tokenise the argument string and then set the individual parameter values.

Your feedback will help. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> `DrawShape("CIRCLE", Radius=20)`

You can pass a table, which will allow you to distinguish between positional and named parameters:

```
DrawShape({"CIRCLE", Radius=20})
```

You can also use syntax sugar that allows you to drop one pair of parentheses in this case:

```
DrawShape{"CIRCLE", Radius=20}
```

You can then get positional parameters using `unpack(t)` (assuming `t` is the table parameter you pass) and get the rest of the parameters using `t.Radius` or iterating over them using `pairs`.

Personally, I'd still stick to `DrawCube` and `DrawCircle`...

Comment: Using tables is a cool trick!
'unpack' seems to be limited to Lua only. For the C++ part, I perhaps need to walk the table. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over elements in the table using `pairs` or access positional elements using `for` loop with `ipairs` or `1, #t` range.